# My facebook app doesnt work anymore, why is that happening?

Tags: facebook, quotes

My [facebook app](https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=157918340311) doesnt work anymore, why is that happening?

Comment: Appears: error charging the page, it started after i received a mail saying that my app was "repaired"

Answer (score 0):

So assuming your app is an FBML app, it looks like your app's landing page is crashing. Check your server's error and access logs.

Answer (score 0):

check developer panel from [here](http://www.facebook.com/developers) for your canvas url address and your app and settings have the matching url working properly

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with application secret key and api key. It seems to be different form facebook and your source code. Please check it once